# How to find if a value is same for all the records in a group SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need your help with a query. I have CustomerID and their family details CustomerID is same for the head of the family and rest of the family members. and there the table holds Person ID, FirstName, LastName and MiddleName.

I want to get all the Customer and family member details information whose middle name is same, we had a mishap when some of the customers got their Middle name updated as same.

Sample Data:

```
create table #testcust (CustID INT, Pid INT, FName VARCHAR(3), LName VARCHAR(3), MName VARCHAR(1))

insert into #testcust

select 11111, 001, 'ABC', 'CDE', 'X'
union all
select 11111, 002, 'CDE', 'CDE', 'X'
union all
select 11111,003, 'XVC', 'CDE', 'X'
union all
select 11111, 004, 'YUS', 'CDE', 'X'
union all
select 11111, 005, 'AHS', 'CDE', 'X'
union all

select 11011, 001, 'OPO', 'ABS', 'X'
union all
select 11011, 002, 'LKJ', 'ABS', 'Y'
union all
select 11011, 003, 'FGS', 'ABS', 'X'
union all

select 21011, 001, 'OLO', 'ABX', 'Y'
union all
select 21011, 002, 'LOJ', 'ABX', 'Y'
union all

select 11031, 001, 'OPO', 'OBS', 'X'
union all
select 11031, 002, 'LKJ', 'OBS', 'Y'
union all
select 11031, 003, 'FGS', 'OBS', 'X'
union all
select 11031, 004, 'OPO', 'OBS', 'X'
union all
select 11031, 005, 'LKJ', 'OBS', 'Y'
union all
select 11031, 006, 'FGS', 'OBS', 'X'
union all

select 10000, 001, 'CDE', 'CDE', 'X'
union all
select 10000, 002, 'XVC', 'CDE', ''  
union all 
select 10000, 003, 'YUS', 'CDE', ''
union all   
select 10000, 004, 'AHS', 'CDE', 'X'

select * from #testcust

drop table #testcust
```

I want to get the details of all the Customers where the middle name is same for all.

Comment: Please post your expected result.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: @HABO yes I have. but it involved sub-queries and joins.

Answer (score 0):

Just GROUP BY CustomerID and COUNT DISTINCT middle names. Then leave only those name that HAVE COUNT=1.

```
SELECT
    CustID
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT MName) AS DistinctMiddleNames
FROM #testcust
GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MName) = 1
ORDER BY CustID;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+---------------------+
| CustID | DistinctMiddleNames |
+--------+---------------------+
|  11111 |                   1 |
|  21011 |                   1 |
+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thank yoy! appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can count the unique number of middle names per customer ID:

```
SELECT  CustID ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Pid) ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT MName)
FROM    #testcust
GROUP BY CustID 
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT MName) = 1
```

Since it's possible to have family members with similar middle names, you improve your query by going case sensitive:

```
SELECT  CustID ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Pid) ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT MName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS )
FROM    #testcust
GROUP BY CustID 
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT MName COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ) = 1
```

You know if have a middle name of "X" and "x" then you know they were not updated with the same "mishap".

Comment: Thank you! appreciate your help!